# Unimportant change in Dynamic

Tags: dynamic, version-10

I just observed an unimportant change in version 10 with respect to `Dynamic`.

The command

```
x=0; Dynamic[x=x+1]
```

returns a cell showing an infinite loop for the value of x.

Before Mathematica 10, this infinite loop could be interrupted by using the frontend toolbar at the top of the window, or equivalently by pressing e.g. Alt+c. In Mathematica 10, the loop is not interrupted when we use the toolbar. Probably that is as intended, though I think it is rather irrelevant whether or not such an infinite loop is paused when using the toolbar. Both in Mathematica 10 and earlier, the loop is interrupted when we use the mouse.

Comment: On a Mac, I see no difference.  The updating is interrupting whenever the user engages the menus or holds the mouse down.  That has been the behavior as far as I can remember.  But perhaps it has changed only on Windows...or Linux.

Comment: Yes, I should have mentioned that I am using Windows.

Comment: Confirmed on Windows 8.1. I'm thinking it could be a change in the FrontEnd (maybe the FE is implemented using technology  related to Dynamic).